# Can't capture a member variable in a lambda by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using TargetsType = std::map<float, std::string>;
using TimesType = std::set<float>;

void foo (const TargetsType& targets,
          const TimesType& times)
{
    for (const auto& target : targets)
    {
        // fails to compile
        TimesType::const_iterator iter1 = std::find_if(times.begin(),
                                                       times.end(),
                                                       [&(target.first)](float item) 
                                                       {
                                                           return std::fabs(item - target.first) < 0.1f;
                                                       });

        // compiles OK
        TimesType::const_iterator iter2 = std::find_if(times.begin(),
                                                       times.end(),
                                                       [&](float item) 
                                                       {
                                                           return std::fabs(item - target.first) < 0.1f;
                                                       });
    }
}
```

The declaration of `iter1` fails to compile with the following error:

```
error: expected ',' before '(' token
```

but the declaration of `iter2` is OK.

Can someone explain why the first declaration doesn't compile?

Comment: @Tyker I tried that first. Same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[&(target.first)](float item) {
    return std::fabs(item - target.first) < 0.1f;
}
```

You can't do `[&(target.first)]`. Even without the parentheses, you cannot capture a single member variable like that. You need to use C++14's capture inits:

```
[&first = target.first](float item) {
    return std::fabs(item - first) < 0.1f;
}
```

Or alternatively, following your second lambda, capture just `target`:

```
[&target](float item) {
    return std::fabs(item - target.first) < 0.1f;
}
```